# Is the solution of this complex numbers system correct?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a system of two equations that need to be satisfied simultaneously, where $A,B,x,y\in\mathbb{C}$; they have the form:
\begin{eqnarray}
Ax=-yB\nonumber\\
B\bar{x}=-\bar{y}A
\end{eqnarray}
where $\bar{z}$ represents the complex conjugate of a complex number $z$. We aim to solve for $A,B$, more explicitly, the ratio between both, without making any assumptions on the form of $A,B,x,y$.

We can obtain by dividing them that:
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)^{2}=\frac{\bar{x}y}{x\bar{y}}=e^{i2\theta},
\end{eqnarray}
where $\theta$ is a phase angle that will generally be given by:
\begin{eqnarray}
\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{\text{Im}(\bar{x}y)}{\text{Re}(\bar{x}y)}\right).
\end{eqnarray}
Is this solution a valid one? Otherwise, I assume the system has no "non-trivial" solution. The only important ratio to determine is $A/B$.

Comment: The system always has a solution, since $(0,0)$ is always a solution...

Comment: We aim to solve for $A/B$. If $A=\bar{B}$, then the second equation is just the first equation conjugated. But a priori, $A$ need not be $\bar{B}$, so I would say one just solves taking into account the two equations, as I wrote above. The important question is how would one, in general, go on solving such system of simultaneous equations, without assuming anything in the form of $A,B$,

Comment: As pointed by 5xum, $(A,B)=(0,0)$ is always a solution. So you can "aim to solve for $A,B$" but not for "the ratio between both" (which is moreover not "more explicit").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system has non-zero solutions $(A,B)\in\Bbb C^2$ iff $|x|=|y|.$

Assuming $x\ne0$ and $y=xe^{i\theta},$ the solutions are simply $(-e^{i\theta}B,B)$ ($B\in\Bbb C$).

Your formulation is not correct because it would also allow $(+e^{i\theta}B,B).$

Comment: The solution still makes an assumption on $x,y$, that $|x|=|y|$. But then, what is wrong with the approach above of dividing both equations to obtain $(A/B)^{2}$?.

Comment: The answer assumes $|x|=|y|$ only after having solved the system when $|x|\ne|y|.$

Comment: 2 things are wrong with the "approach above". 1: dividing is not legit because $B=0$ for at least one of the solutions. 2: squaring introduces fake "solutions", as pointed at the end of my answer.

Comment: So $A/B=-e^{i\theta}$, with $\theta=\arctan(\text{Im}(-y/x)/\text{Re}(-y/x))$, correct?

Comment: $\theta$ is not that arctan (which is defined only $\bmod\pi$ and would be the same with $-y$ replaced by $y$). $\theta$ is defined $\bmod{2\pi}$ (if $|x|=|y|\ne0$) by $y=xe^{i\theta}.$

Comment: But $|x|\neq |y|$ in general. So, for $|x|\neq |y|$, the only solution is the trivial one, $(0,0)$? In other words, we only have a solution $(-e^{i\theta}B,B)$ (as in the response) if and only if $|x|=|y|$, which is in general not the case.

Comment: Yes, this obvious remark was my 1st sentence. Beware also of the trivial case $x=y=0,$ so your "if and only if" is not completely correct. The solution(S) $(-e^{i\theta}B,B)$ are the only one(S) iff $|x|=|y|\ne0,$ as in the answer.